# Restoring RAW files on NTFS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partition-recovery

I've searched as far as I could to find a solution to my problem, but I can not even really describe my problem shortly. Here's what happened:

One of my 2 TB HDDs is basically dying of age, CrystalDisk won't even give me any info on it anymore and my Win10 system started to boot in slower because of it. About time to get it out, right?
I have another HDD that is the same model in it and I have some important data on it. After unplugging the old HDD Windows booted in faster and detected.. that the newer HDD was the old one? I only stored Temp files on the old one and Windows said it had 1,65 TB left instead of the couple hundreds that were supposed to be stored in the newer. Since they were the same model and size I thought I mixed it up and the system booted in faster because it couldn't handle more than 2 HDDs (yes, I legit thought that for a minute) before swapping it out and to discover that this time I had the old Temp HDD in, booting in slower and Explorer saying, yes, this is the temp hdd with the 1,65 gigs on it. So I decided to wipe it before unplugging it this time, so it couldn't mix it up. I didn't know, though, that Win10 has an issue telling the same HDD model apart from each other by all the other Meta-Data. The new HDD was displayed as wiped, so I plugged in the old one and the new one and it started to read the both HDDs again, the bad one wiped, the other intact. Until I got an error message that the new drive's Recycle Bin was corrupt and asked me if I wanted to delete. First pressed on "no" because I was not entirely sure what that was about. And after trying to open a folder, it started telling me that it does not exist. And infront of my eyes, more folders started disappearing. Just a few left now, with Temp files mixed in it and the reminders of the new one left unreadable.

I can recover the files with PhotoRec (TestDisk), but it will leave me with a mess that I could look through many weeks just to find the really important things on it. I am as of now trying MiniTool Power Data to scan everything, some of the file trees are actually there and make it easier to find what I am looking for. But I have yet to finish the scan to find out if it can fully display the old state of it.
Currently, most data is displayed as RAW Data, I can see the file type but not where it's from.

Is there any way I can actually restore the HDD to what it was before the mess? I have not messed with it, but Windows is giving me the hardest time.

I am really looking forward to your answers, this is giving me the biggest of headaches..

Answer (score 0):

You might as well mail it in to a data recovery service. I tried doing a windows drive recovery on my drive and ended up deleting more files from drive usage causing more damage. It turns out my drive had a crashed head and required several donor drives in order to recover my files.

Data recovery services cost me $2000 Canadian dollars for my 4 terabyte drive and now I use a certain online constant cloud backup solution for $6 a month to back up all my terabytes of data. I got my drive back in a month with 99.9% of my data and they even gave me a list of all the files they could not recover. But this was 1-2 years before COVID 19 times. However my drive didn't turn into raw data like yours did.

Is your data worth $2000? Or whatever price they estimate?

Comment: I can relate to the recovery services pricing in germany. However, it's one thing to believe your data being worth the money, it's another thing to HAVE the money for the service.
Even though I was not able to figure out the main issue, I can say that using free software I was able to recover at least the important of them all. And I will check out the degree of corruption when it's completed, but it's great to see some of it back.